# Re-sodding to solve weed problem without use of herbicides

Tags: lawn, weeds, herbicide, sod, dandelions

Our lawn is overridden with weeds (mostly dandelions and clover).  Part of the problem is we have not done much to maintain it over the years and also we don't use any herbicides.  I wanted to tear up the current lawn and put in new sod.  The company I spoke to said they would dig out about 3 to 4 inches and put in a fertilizer (I made it clear no herbicide) and put in about 2 inches of triple mix and resod. They think this should solve the weed problem. Another landscaper I spoke to seemed to think this is a waste and they will just grow back if we don't use a herbicide first to kill them, as the roots can go deeper than the 3 to 4 inches.  Can somebody please advise? (We live in Mississauga, Canada)

Comment: Your choice, of course, but don't forget thatt one gardener’s weedy lawn is another gardener's wildflower meadow. Unless you're maintaining a sports turf surface such as a tennis court or bowling green why worry about dandelions and clover?

Answer (score 1):

The second landscaper is right. If you get someone else to do the job, they will either need to kill the weeds with herbicide, or they need to dig out each weed separately, extracting all root material, and that may mean going down 8 inches or more to get out a dandelion root. If this is not done, they will regrow through the new lawn.

Comment: The first landscaper may be betting that they won't regrow for a few months, after which if you complain about the work he can say "no, I killed all the weeds that were originally there, these are new ones."

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to resod as chickens work well on grass, and there should be diversify in grass so you don't need to fertilize as much if you do. The number is depending on the size of the area you're stripping of plant life.

Answer (score 0):

That's overkill and expensive, weeds like dandelion and clover are indicative tell tale signs of lawn health.

- Clover, lack of nitrogen
- dandelion: compacted soil
  Better strategy is to mow the lawn down golf course style short and let it regrow, then manually remove any weed that pops up. Also your soil may be compacted so it's best to aerate and seed.